# read text from the current directory in java

Tags: java

i have written a program that reads contents from a text file. the program will check the contents of the text for a particular phrase is in it or not. if yes it will replace the phrase in the content with #.  The program works fine, but I am reading the file by writing the complete path explicitly.

like this

```
Path fileName = Path.of("E:\\java\\program\\src\\textfile.txt");
```

I want to change that. I need to read the file from the directory without writing the complete path explicitly. just the name of the text file. since they are in the same folder. how can i do that?

The structure of the folder is like this

```
E:
----java
-----------program
-------------------src
------------------------textfile.txt
------------------------App.java
```

Both App.java and the text file are in the same folder

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.FileWriter;

class App{
    static String censor(String text,String word) throws IOException {
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                stars += '#';
            } else {
                stars += ' ';
            }
        text = text.replaceAll(word, stars);

        File path = new File("E:\\java\\program\\src\\newtextfile.txt");
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(path);
        wr.write(text);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path fileName = Path.of("E:\\java\\program\\src\\textfile.txt");
        String extract = Files.readString(fileName);
        String cen = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
        System.out.println(censor(extract, cen));
    }
}
```

Comment: How will the application know which directory to look in? And how will it know which file (out of possibly many) to read?

Comment: look at `Class.getResource`

Comment: Where is class GFG in your project structure?

Comment: @k314159
What i meant is that i don't want to write the entire path explicitly. but only writing the file name. because both are in the same folder right

Comment: actually i am new to java

Comment: @Jens can you explain little more

Comment: have you tried this? File path = new File("newtextfile.txt");

Comment: I think it is clearly described in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: @maddy23285
 it works for writing the file not reading

Answer (score 0):

When you run an application, you are not running the `App.java` file directly. That file is compiled into an `App.class` file, and Java then runs your `App.class` file. The class file is probably created in a different directory, and when you run your application it doesn't know which directory the original `App.java` file was in (or even if it still exists or not).

What you can do is use the concept of **current directory**. If you just try to open the file using only its name (e.g. `new File("textfile.txt")`) it will look for that file in the current directory. You can tell your IDE which directory to run the application in. If you run the application from the command line, then you can `cd` to the correct directory before you run the application.

To be confirm which directory it's looking in, you can do this:

```
Path path = Path.of("textfile.txt").toAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("Trying to open file " + path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply substitute your file path with the file name in the consor method. In your main method you may use Path.get() for the existing file. Your code should look like this then:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.io.FileWriter;

class App{
    static String censor(String text,String word) throws IOException {
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                stars += '#';
            } else {
                stars += ' ';
            }
        text = text.replaceAll(word, stars);

        File path = new File("newtextfile.txt");
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(path);
        wr.write(text);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path fileName = Paths.get("textfile.txt");
        String extract = Files.readString(fileName);
        String cen = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
        System.out.println(censor(extract, cen));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `Path.get`; it's either `Path.of` or `Paths.get`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the file and the app jar file will be in the same directory you can  use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to determine the current working directory of the app. In your case the name of the current working directory would be `program`.

You only want the filename to be set explicitly i assume you mean setting the file name with a java argument. The code below shows you how you can make a `Path` object using the current working directory as well as a user defined file name.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.FileWriter;

class App{
    static String censor(String text,String word) throws IOException {
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                stars += '#';
            } else {
                stars += ' ';
            }
        text = text.replaceAll(word, stars);

        File path = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "newtextfile.txt").toFile();
        FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(path);
        wr.write(text);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path fileName = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), args[0]);
        String extract = Files.readString(fileName);
        String cen = "consectetur adipiscing elit";
        System.out.println(censor(extract, cen));
    }
}
```

You would run your app like this: `java -jar App.jar filename.txt`

EDIT: Make sure your file is in the directory `program` as well and not in a subdirectory of `program`.